# Give a dropdown a default value with php

Tags: php, mysql, html, sql, drop-down-menu

i would like to give a dropdown a default value with php / mysql queries

like in the db table users there is a record saying usergroup

and i want it so the dropdown default value changes to the value of that record i got this code so far:

```
Usergroup: <select value=\"" . $usergroup . "\" name='usergroup'>
<option value='4'>Administrator</option>
<option value='3'>Moderator</option>
<option value='2'>Donator</option>
<option value='1'>Regular Member</option>
</select>
```

and php part:

```
 $username = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities(stripslashes($_POST['username'])));
  $query="SELECT * FROM users where `username` like '{$username}'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

$num = mysql_numrows($result);

$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
$username2=mysql_result($result,$i,"username");
$name=mysql_result($result,$i,"name");
$usergroup=mysql_result($result,$i,"usergroup");
$email=mysql_result($result,$i,"email");
$ip=mysql_result($result,$i,"ip");
$profpic=mysql_result($result,$i,"profilepic");
$id=mysql_result($result,$i,"id");
$i++;
}
```

thanks in regards!

i gotten it to work with a few if statements, i was planning to use it that way but didn't want the code to become too messy:

```
if ($usergroup == 4) {
echo "<select name='usergroup'><option value='4' selected='selected'>Administrator</option><option value='3'>Moderator</option><option value='2'>Donator</option><option value='1'>Regulat Member</option></select><br>";
}
if ($usergroup == 3) {
echo "<select name='usergroup'><option value='4'>Administrator</option><option value='3' selected='selected'>Moderator</option><option value='2'>Donator</option><option value='1'>Regulat Member</option></select><br>";
}
if ($usergroup == 2) {
echo "<select name='usergroup'><option value='4'>Administrator</option><option value='3'>Moderator</option><option value='2' selected='selected'>Donator</option><option value='1'>Regulat Member</option></select><br>";
}
if ($usergroup == 1) {
echo "<select name='usergroup'><option value='4'>Administrator</option><option value='3'>Moderator</option><option value='2'>Donator</option><option value='1' selected='selected'>Regulat Member</option></select><br>";
}
```

Comment: pre select an option using selected="selected"

Comment: i know but i want it to change according to the database result :s

Comment: like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844244/how-to-select-a-select-statement-from-database

Comment: or should i just use a few if statements so i just code multiple dropdowns with a different selected option?

Comment: You can put a few `IF`'s (or ternary operators...) in the options so only the right one has `selected` on it.

Comment: http://puu.sh/Pq7o it works the way i said,

Answer (score 2):

This is probably what you are looking for:

```
<?php
  // $userGroup = the value from the database
  $userGroup = 4;
?>

<select>
  <option <?php echo ($userGroup) == 1 ? "selected" : "" ?> value="1">Administrator</option>
  <option <?php echo ($userGroup) == 2 ? "selected" : "" ?> value="2">Moderator</option>
  <option <?php echo ($userGroup) == 3 ? "selected" : "" ?> value="3">Donator</option>
  <option <?php echo ($userGroup) == 4 ? "selected" : "" ?> value="4">Regular member</option>
</select>
```

If you don't recognize the if/else syntax (shorthand), [check out this guide](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-shorthand-if-else-examples). Really handy for situations like this.