# How to select a <select> statement from database?

Tags: php, mysql, html, database

I wasnt quite sure how to word the question correctly - but this is merely just out of interest really.  Constantly I am having to load information from a database and pre-populate a form with the values.  So in the case of the textbox, its easy, i simply set the value:

`<input type="text" value="<?=$foo;?>" name="foobar">`

However when I come to select boxes I find my code gets quite sloppy, as I need to place a `selected` value in the line somewhere.  So really I have two options, both of which I dislike:

```
$one = $two = "";
switch ($myval) {
  case "1": $one = " selected";
  case "2": $two = " selected";

}
```

and then in the HTML:

```
<select name="myval">
<option value="1"<?=$one;?>>One</option>
<option value="1"<?=$two;?>>Two</option>
</select>
```

Or the other option is to place a shorthand if statement in the middle of the select:

```
<select name="myval">
<option value="1"<?=($myval=="1") ? " selected" : "";?>>One</option>
<option value="1"<?=($myval=="2") ? " selected" : "";?>>Two</option>
</select>
```

Which looks slightly cleaner, however it still bugs me.

Anyone got any much more efficent ways of doing this? its even more annyoing when It is just a `Yes/No` drop downbox and I have to write stupid if statements for each value.

The same question applies to checkboxes as well.

Comment: IF statements are not `stupid`

Comment: in this case it just seems a bit long and pointless for such a simple task.

Comment: i think last option you specified is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an addition to Quentin (just some code to help you out), I tend to use arrays as well, like this:

```
<select name="myval">
    <?php
        $options = array(
            "1" => "One",
            "2" => "Two"
        );
        foreach ($options as $value => $text) {
            echo '<option value="' . $value . '"' . ($myval == $value ? ' selected' : '') . '>' . $text . '</option>';
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: @tehlulz I wasnt looking for answers, just suggestions, if you look the code is the same as mine essentially.

Comment: @Chud37 no its not, you use an IF statement on every option, the loop in this answer has only `one` IF and loops all your options..

Answer (score 5):

Create an array with the data you want in the output. Loop over it. Generate an option element for each item in it.

Comment: This is what I do, but I also have a function that I pass it to, in the arguments, I pass the ID that I am interested in and if the row matches, I throw in the `selected` tag. +1

Answer (score 1):

Well the easiest way for such repetitive outputs is to write yourself a function, for example:

```
function selectbox(array $options, $name, $value = null) {
    $out = '<select name="' . $name . '">';
    foreach($options as $key => $text) {
        $out .= '<option value="' . $key. '"' . ($key == $value ? ' selected="selected"' : null) . '>' . $text . '</option>';
    }

    return $out . '</select>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are really many ways for a cleaner code. Find one or invent your own :)

For select statements, I like to use utility methods. E.g.:

```
<?= HTML::createSelect($name, $actualvalue, $optionslist, $passthrough) ?>
```

Something on that line. Read the optionslist and the actualvalue from the DB. Passthrough is for adding HTML decorators, e.g. id, class, etc.

Comment: Aha yes well the point of asking my question was to see what others did.  But I have never seen this before - I shall look it up.

Comment: I cant find any documentation on HTML::createSelect?? Is that one of your own functions?

Comment: Sure, it's a method I wrote. This is just an example. Most MVC frameworks have similar "form helpers" to generate form elements. Makes the code look cleaner, and you do less boiler-plating.